# Use a variable in C# path

Tags: c#

I need to save an .xml file in a specific location on a computer. But location could be changed based on selection of the user.

I can get user selection (from combobox) to the variable like this:

```
location = (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

But I can’t use following command to store my file because of “%location%” part. It says “Could not find a part of the path”

```
docSave.Save(@"C:\...\...\%location%\...\Information.xml");
```

Can anyone help me regarding that….?

Thank you.

Comment: Which part of the string did the user actually type in? The whole `"C:......\%location%...\Information.xml"` string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always use the `Path` class when you're working with paths, so if you want to get a working path from multiple parts, use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx):

```
string location = (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
string dir = "C:\dir1\dir2\%location%\dir4".Replace("%location%", location);
string filename = "Information.xml";
string fullPath = Path.Combine(dir, filename);
```

Answer (score 6):

`String.Format` is what you are looking for.

```
string.Format("C:\\...{0}\\Information.xml", location);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to expand an environment string that has been typed in with % delimiters such as `%environmentVariableName%`, you can use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx)

For example:

```
string expandedEnvString = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\\Something");
```

This will work with multiple environment variables, so long as each is delimited with `%` characters, and you can have other strings mixed in with them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use string.format to put the variable in the path:

```
docSave.Save(string.Format(@"C:......\{0}...\Information.xml", location));
```